# Python: Using NiBabel to write .hdr/.img nifti files

Tags: python, dicom, nifti

Attempting to go from dicom to nifti using nibabel. looking for the way to save the header and image seperately, ive done the rest.

nibabel.Nifti1Header has a write_to function but only takes a fileobj. how do i pass the Nifti1Header instance with a save file pathname to that method? says needs 2 arguments but then you put a string pathname and it doesnt like the string.

nibabel.save method takes the img matrix, the affine and the header however can only save in the combination .nii format which changes the "magic" element in the header dictionary to n+1 instead of ni1 which is required for seperate .hdr/.img

I have my header all ready to go, and the image, just cant find the methods to save them each.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 2):

For those interested,

```py
import nibabel as nib


img = nib.Nifti1Image(array, affine, header)

nib.nifti1.save(img, os.getcwd()+'{}'.format(r'\test.img'))
```

this will save separate .img and .hdr files